# TFS Checkin plocies for different version of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, checkin, checkin-policy

I created a Custom  Checkin policy and build it in Visual Studio 2013 and also build it in Visual Studio 2012 so that whoever using Vs 2012 can use the policy and successfully registered the policy to all machines. I applied the policy to a Team Project from my computer which has VS 2013. In our company some people still use VS 2012. Now whoever is using VS 2012 having issue on checkin. They get this error: **`Internal error in [Policy Name] policy. Error loading the [Policy Name] policy. Installation instructions: PLease see the web based installation instructions.`**

So does everybody in our company needs to upgrade to VS 2013?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the 2013 created policy and add it with 2012. It should then upscale to 2013.

Its the backward compat that's an issue...

Answer (score 0):

The people with VS2012 should un-install 2013 version policy and install a policy with references to TFS2012 dlls.